# Amend code to allow difference for specific account

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm new to apex and I am trying to amend code left by our old developer. On our object "action plan" we have a series of rules that apply to all. I need to change this so when the "project" field is set to a specific name, a different time period is allowed.

Need to insert a condition that this 91 day is expanded to 182 days when project__c is a specific name.

Have tried to muddle my way through using IF functions but my syntax is wrong.

```
if(ap.Date__c > (AP.CreatedDate + 91) ){
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error, Action Plan was created more than 3 months ago'));
return null;
}
```

Error messages have all been about syntax `(";" expected where } was found`" etc.,) though when I make suggested changes, often contradictory error messages are presented about the syntax.

Comment: This code as posted appears to be valid. Can you please include one incarnation of the code that is not working and the specific error message? Please note that you may need to add more context as Apex syntax errors sometimes show up just after the actual problem.

Comment: Hi David, This is the code I am looking to amend as our developer left it, I am very new to apex and was wondering if there were any suggestions to how this should be phrased, as I have very little idea if what I have attempted previously is even in the ballpark,